# SQL Join with MAX function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created two tables in sql....

1.Product

with

```
ProductId as Primary key,
ProductName,ProductPrice 
and ProductCategoryId as Foreign Key
```

which refers to the `primary key of ProductCategory table`.

2.ProductCategory

with

```
CategoryId as Primary Key and CategoryName.
```

I want to display the Product having max price in each category.....

Suppose there are two categories..

```
1.Soap 
2.Shampoo.
```

and in Product Table there are 4 rows...

```
1.Dove Soap with price 42Rs
2.Dettol Soap with price 25Rs
3.Dove Shampoo with price 120Rs and
4.Sunsilk Shampoo with Price 140Rs
```

Then Output should be like....

1.Dove Soap,Price 42,Category Name Soap.
2.Sunsilk Shampoo,price 140,Category Name Shampoo.

Pls reply the sql query for this using join operation.

Comment: Did you tried something *before* asking?

maybe you should ask your teacher.

Comment: Can there be an item with two same max values for one category? like another soap but its price is 42Rs as well? If this is possible how do  you want to show them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH MaxValues
AS
(
SELECT MAX(p.ProductPrice) MaxPrice, p.ProductCategoryId ProductCategoryId
FROM Product p 
GROUP BY p.ProductCategoryId
)
SELECT p.ProductName, m.MaxPrice, c.CategoryName
FROM MaxValues m JOIN Product p ON m.ProductCategoryId = p.ProductCategoryId
JOIN ProductCategory c ON p.ProductCategoryId = c.CategoryId
WHERE p.ProductPrice = m.MaxPrice
```